# SAP B1: Sales and Returns in one query

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

I'm a new in SAP B1.
Have a task to show the Sales and Returns for the period by BP in one query and after to create the Crystal Report based on data.
ORDR and RDR1 - Sales
ORDN and RDN1 - Returns.
Can you please advise how can I join them?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not use the CardCode of the businessPartner ? both sales orders and returns have this field.

Comment: Details of the request:
- In the period from Jan 1st  to June 30 I want to use the sales and returns for each ItemCode group by BP, like:

BP Code | ItemCode | Total Sale | Total Return
C-BSC    | 12-08-SI   |  5              | 1
U-IIK       | 07-12-CL  | 1               | 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive data from both business objects (orders and returns) you should think about UNIONing them instead of JOINing.
A pure SQL query (HANA flavor in this example) would look like this:

```
SELECT 
     "CardCode"
    ,"ItemCode"
    ,SUM("Total Sale") AS "Total Sale"
    ,SUM("Total Return") AS "Total Return"
FROM
(
    SELECT
         ORDR."CardCode"
        ,RDR1."ItemCode"
        ,RDR1."Quantity" AS "Total Sale"
        ,0 AS "Total Return"
    FROM ORDR
    JOIN RDR1
        ON ORDR."DocEntry" = RDR1."DocEntry"
    WHERE ORDR."DocDate" BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-06-30'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
         ORDN."CardCode"
        ,RDN1."ItemCode"
        ,0 AS "Total Sale"
        ,RDN1."Quantity" AS "Total Return"
    FROM ORDN
    JOIN RDN1
        ON ORDN."DocEntry" = RDN1."DocEntry"
    WHERE ORDN."DocDate" BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-06-30'
)
GROUP BY
     "CardCode"
    ,"ItemCode"
```

To get the results into Crystal Reports (CR) there are quite some options. You may try to

- create a database view from the query shown above and query that view from CR
- or create a database view from the inner query above (i.e. the one in round brackets), query that from CR, and do the grouping in CR
- or use CR's "Command" as data source, and build the command like you would create a database view.

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft SQL Server
Added CANCELED='N'

```
SELECT
a.[CardCode], 
a.[CardName], 
a.[ItemCode], 
SUM(a.TotalSale)[TotalSale], 
SUM(a.TotalReturn) [TotalReturn]

FROM
(

SELECT DISTINCT 
T0.[CardCode], 
T0.[CardName], 
T1.[ItemCode], 
SUM(T1.[Quantity]) as 'TotalSale', 
0 as 'TotalReturn'

FROM ORDR T0  
INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry]
WHERE T0.[CANCELED] ='N' 
GROUP BY 
T0.[CardCode], 
T0.[CardName], 
T1.[ItemCode]

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT 
T0.[CardCode], 
T0.[CardName], T1.[ItemCode], 
0 as 'TotalSale',
SUM(T1.[Quantity]) as 'TotalReturn'

FROM ORDN T0  INNER JOIN RDN1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
WHERE T0.[CANCELED] ='N' 
GROUP BY 
T0.[CardCode], 
T0.[CardName], 
T1.[ItemCode]

)  as a

GROUP BY 
a.[CardCode], 
a.[CardName], 
a.[ItemCode]
```